# Disable enter key when page load

Tags: jquery

I want to disable enter key when focus is on drop-down box or focus is passed from the current screen.

I have tried this

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyIdentifier == 'U+000A' || e.keyIdentifier == 'Enter' || e.keyCode == 13) {
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'INPUT' && e.target.type == 'text') {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }
}, true);
```

But it only disable enter key when focus is on input field. I want to disabled on entire page even if focus is passed the current screen.

Comment: by `even if focus is passed the current screen` do you mean focus is on a new window?

Comment: Yes focus is on another window which are already opened

Comment: Anyone please suggest something

Comment: There is a very small chance if the two windows are related you can use `addEventListener` and `window.postMessage` technique (*Try googling these terms*) , else they are pretty independent views and they are designed to not be controllable by other windows.

Comment: And how to prevent enter key when focus is on drop-down list